The login event is not getting triggered after scanning the qr code. Can see the heartbeat only. What's wrong am I doing?
require("dotenv").config();

const { WechatyBuilder, ScanStatus, log } = require("wechaty");
const qrCodeTerminal = require("qrcode-terminal");
const { PuppetWhatsapp } = require("wechaty-puppet-whatsapp");

const puppet = new PuppetWhatsapp();

const wechaty = WechatyBuilder.build({
  puppet,
}); // get a Wechaty instance
wechaty
  .on("scan", (qrcode, status) => {
    // console.log(`Scan QR Code to login: ${status}\nhttps://wechaty.js.org/qrcode/${encodeURIComponent(qrcode)}`)
    console.log("status :>> ", status);
    if (status === ScanStatus.Waiting || status === ScanStatus.Timeout) {
      qrCodeTerminal.generate(qrcode, { small: true });
      const qrcodeImageUrl = [
        "https://wechaty.js.org/qrcode/",
        encodeURIComponent(qrcode),
      ].join("");
      log.info(
        "StarterBot",
        "onScan: %s(%s) - %s",
        ScanStatus[status],
        status,
        qrcodeImageUrl
      );
    }
  })
  .on("login", (user) => console.log(`User ${user} logged in`))
  .on("message", (message) => console.log(`Message: ${message}`))
  .on("ready", () => console.log("Wechaty is ready"))
  .on("error", (error) => console.error("Error: " + error))
  .on("heartbeat", (data) => console.log("heartbeat", data))
  .on("logout", (user) => console.log(`User ${user} logged out`));
wechaty
  .start()
  .then(() => console.log("Wechaty started"))
  .catch((e) => console.error(e))
  .finally(() => console.log("Wechaty started"));

